# Loading Screen using PersistGate doesn't render

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-persist

I'm using redux-persist and I'm trying to render a screen passing it to the loading prop of PersistGate.

I did some research and I found that I should dispatch REHYDRATE to the reducer but that doesn't work either.

Maybe I'm not configuring my reducers well?
I would also like to be able to set the loading prop to null to avoid the flash screen before the App renders, but the result is the same as passing it a component to render.

This is my code of index.js

```js
import App from './App';
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import { SplashScreen } from './src/screens/SplashScreen';
import configureStore from './src/store/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();
const persistor = configureStore();

const RNRedux = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={<SplashScreen/>} persistor={persistor}>
            <App />
        </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
);

componentDidMount = () => {
    this.persistor.dispatch({ type: REHYDRATE });
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Sharryapp', () => RNRedux);
```

And that's my configureStore file:

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import ServerReducer from './reducers/ServerReducer';
import InviteReducer from './reducers/InviteReducer';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    server: ServerReducer,
    invite: InviteReducer,
});

const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    debug: true,
    storage, 
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const store = createStore(persistedReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));

const persistor = persistStore(store);

export default configureStore = () => {
    return ( store, persistor );
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure why you wrap your store and persistor in a configureStore function.
Instead import both separately:

```
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer,applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

And import them in your desired file:

```
import {store, persistor} from './src/store/configureStore';
```

I have also noticed that your createStore call is false, since enhancers are passed as the third parameter. Change it to:

```
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, undefined, applyMiddleware(thunk));
```

That should do it.

Also you do not need to dispatch a rehydrate action as it happens automatically on app start.

Comment: Thank you for answering this. The problem is that when I try to export the store and the persistor to import them together, I get this error on the emulator:
"undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,_configureStore2.default)()')" on index.js line 9

Comment: Are you sure you followed my syntax? I need your code to be more certain but I think you export both as default which is why it breaks.

Comment: Yeah on configureStore.js i made:
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer,undefined,applyMiddleware(thunk));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

And on index.js: import { store, persistor} from './src/store/configureStore';

Comment: Do you have multiple default exports in your configureStore file? Double check if you have the correct path to configureStore. The syntax is correct. Alternatively you could do:     import * as configureStore from 'your-path'; and then access both functions with dot-notation e.g. configureStore.store

Comment: I don't have any default export, just the 2 export const of provider and store

Comment: I solved this error but still, the PersistGate won't render the loading screen

Comment: @QuimBagetSalarich, did you solve rendering of splash screen